# How do I find elements hidden by knockout with Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I have a "Logout" button in a user portal that I don't get to grab.
The frontend is knockout.js and the framework for testing is Selenium.

Now I can get many elements via the ID, but not this logout button. 
A lot of help on the Internet is already outdated and I just can't get any further.

```
<button name="logout" class="btn btn-primary" data-action="userLogout" data-bind="click: logout" data-i18n="app:modules.localization.generals.button.logout">Abmelden</button>
```

This is the source code of the button.

For example, if I execute this code

```
webDriver.FindElement(By.Id("logout")).Click();
```

I get this message

> Message: Test method MyFirstAutomaticTest.UnitTest1.StartPage threw exception: 
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot click on element (MoveTargetOutOfBounds)

Can someone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to `click()` on the element with text as **Abmelden** you can use either of the following solutions:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  webDriver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("button.btn.btn-primary[data-action='userLogout']")).Click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  webDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[@class='btn btn-primary' and @data-action='userLogout']")).Click();
  ```

**Note**: As the element is an Angular element you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be clickable*.

Answer (score 0):

You have bind name attribute as ID,

Try this,

```
webDriver.FindElement(By.name("logout")).Click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with xpath

```
webDriver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//button[text()='Abmelden']")).Click();
```